# How to do the last three steps in a Django allauth post-installation?

Tags: python, django, facebook, django-allauth, google-authentication

I saw someone else had an issue at the same part over a year ago, but no answer was found.

I don't know what these last three steps need of me.

> 1. Add a Site for your domain, matching settings.SITE_ID (django.contrib.sites app).
> 2. For each OAuth based provider, add a Social App (socialaccount app).
> 3. Fill in the site and the OAuth app credentials obtained from the provider.

Here are my questions:

1. What site do I need to add? I'm in development, and have no domain name, do I use my local http://127.0.0.1:8000/
2. Second part asks for: (I don't know what to enter for any of these)

   - User
   - provider
   - uid
3. Third part asks for:

   - provider, a drop down from the ones I added to installed apps (that shows up)
   - client id (where do I get this from Google / Facebook)
   - secret key (where do I get this from Google / Facebook)
   - asks me to add site (the one I don't know what info to add in first step)

I looked for other instructions, or guides, but didn't find anything useful.

I am using Django 1.9 and Python 3.5.

Comment: I did go to Google and Facebook developers sites, and got client ids and secret keys.  That only takes care of parts of part 3 though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If memory serves, django-allauth and python social auth are similar enough that this should still be useful

1. For hostname, you can do one of two things:

   1. use 127.0.0.1:8080 (though I think at least some providers will complain)
   2. use sierra.kilo.com:8080 and put that in your /etc/hosts file (or the windows equivalent) for development
2. I would suggest picking one provider to start if memory serves, google was slightly pickier than twitter for my configuration; have not used facebook.
3. This is going to depend on the provider... for twitter, go to https://apps.twitter.com/ to register your app and therefore get the client id / secret key (and therefore add the site).  For google, https://console.developers.google.com/projectselector/apis/credentials is your starting point to register your project and get the credentials

(Just saw comment, which obviates the part I spent time on, but hopefully point 1 at least is useful for that part of the question)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'd like to add a few notes in case anyone else sees this one day. With Facebook I had to enter hostname:port# for the url 127.0.0.1 wasnt accepted.

Facebooks developer page had very good documentation on how to set up the app and get the cid and secret key.

Comment: +Foon Now I have the login button on my page, and am able to log in with my facebook account, but I am trying to figure out whats next.  I don't actually get any of their user information sent to my user accounts, or anything.  What needs to be set up next?